flutter i want to remove the extra icon that is overflowing out of my card
is it possible to make my icon fit in my card without the extra overflow i wanted my icon to tilt like that and only 70 to 80 percent of calendar icon to stay inside the card , send help pls i am beginner :) thanks for help in advance
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Calendarview()));
  },
  child: WidgetAnimator(
    incomingEffect: WidgetTransitionEffects.incomingSlideInFromBottom(duration: Duration(seconds: 1)),
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        elevation: 10,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        ),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  angle: 320 * pi / 180,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_month,
                    size: 120,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
  ),
),



I am wondering why clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias isn't working  Does it happen without WidgetAnimator?

i tried it without WidgetAnimator its still not worky

Wrap Align with ClipRRect widget.

You can override the clipBehavior of the Card widget to fix it.
Card(
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  elevation: 10,


Glad to help,you can find more about layout
